# How can I get TortoiseHG to reload options in Mercurial.ini?

Tags: windows, tortoisehg

For what it's worth I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit SP1 and TortoiseHG version 2.8.

The yellow scheme for the `status.unknown` items works well on a black background of the command line but not on the white background of the GUI.

I added `red_background` to the `status.unknown` line in the `[color]` section of `Mercurial.ini`. It changed the output of the `hg status` command as expected.

I went back to the GUI version and there was no change. I thought it must need to be reloaded so I went to Global settings for the GUI, made a change to an option, saved it then changed it back. I thought it would cause a reload of the options.  No change.

It did say to restart all TortoiseHG programs but I had nothing else open.

Barring a lengthy restart of the machine what should I do?

**Update #1**

It seems that the GUI ignores the background values in the `[color]` section.  I changed the color to blue (unreadable in the command prompt), rebooted and the text became blue in the GUI, but the background stayed white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TortoiseHG reads `Mercurial.ini` on the fly. After I rebooted the computer I could change the colors without doing anything other than updating the ini file.